# Does OAuth token (from mobile SDK) still work in local browser?

Tags: security, mobile, oauth2, web

I'm working on the Mobile app development. Here is my issue:

1. We have got a token through the OAuth flow in App using SDK.
2. There is a link in app named "user info", user tap that link and open a local browser and see what he wish to see in that browser without log in again.

Step 1 is OK, my question is there any solutions for step 2 ?

I mean can I use the token authorized in Mobile APP to access web salesforce in local browser without log in again ?

If it does, hope to provide some relevant reference or samples.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by `frontdoor.jsp` page. You need to navigate user to following url on button click:

> `https://instance.salesforce.com/secur/frontdoor.jsp?sid=access_token&retURL=start_page`

- instance is the Salesforce instance i.e; na9
- access_token is the token you got from OAuth flow
- retURL is the start page you want to show on login

Note: You have to provide **`web`** scope in OAuth flow.

Comment: Thanks for you answer Regal.

I think the "secure/frontdoor.jsp" should be "secur/frontdoor.jsp".

I test it many times, it seems not work as before. I set the OAuth scope as "Access and manage your data(api),Provide access to your data via the Web(web),Full access (full)".

Then I got the access_token in App SDK "abcdef", and visit URL in browser "https://na1.salesforce.com/secur/frontdoor.jsp?sid=abcdef"(na1 is my instance).
The browser navigate to "https://na1.salesforce.com/saml/authn-request.jsp?request_id=...&..." and pop a dialog tell me to input username and password.

Comment: @RobinLi Yes, it should be  "secur/frontdoor.jsp".

Comment: Do you have a working example of this?  I experience the same behavior as Robin, even when my scope contains **web** and **full**.

Comment: Maybe an encoding issue? Do you need to URL encode the access token? I can't remember if there are sometimes characters that are not URL safe.